# Is this correct for disposing an object using IDisposable

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class that implements the IDisposable interface. I am using a webclient to download some data using the AsyncDownloadString.

I am wondering have I correctly declared my event handlers in the constructor and within the using statement of the web client? And is this correct way to remove the event handlers in the Dispose method?

Overrule is this the correct way to use the IDisposable interface?

```
public class Balance : IDisposable
{
    //Constructor
    WebClient wc;
    public Balance()
    {
        using (wc = new WebClient())
        {
            //Create event handler for the progress changed and download completed events
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        }
    }

    ~Balance()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    //Get the current balance for the user that is logged in.
    //If the balance returned from the server is NULL display error to the user.
    //Null could occur if the DB has been stopped or the server is down.       
    public void GetBalance(string sipUsername)
    {
        //Remove the underscore ( _ ) from the username, as this is not needed to get the balance.
        sipUsername = sipUsername.Remove(0, 1);

        string strURL =
            string.Format("https://www.xxxxxxx.com", 
            sipUsername);

        //Download only when the webclient is not busy.
        if (!wc.IsBusy)
        { 
            // Download the current balance.
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(strURL));             
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Busy please try again");
        }
    }

    //return and display the balance after the download has fully completed
    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Pass the result to the event handler
    }

    //Dispose of the balance object
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    //Remove the event handlers
    private bool isDisposed = false;
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.isDisposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                wc.DownloadProgressChanged -= new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
                wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);

                wc.Dispose();
            }               
            isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is mostly correct except `wc` is being disposed twice and `GetBalance` will always be using `wc` after it's disposed!

Edit: a version with that correction:

```
public class Balance : IDisposable
{
    //Constructor
    WebClient wc;
    public Balance()
    {
        wc = new WebClient();
        //Create event handler for the progress changed and download completed events
        try {
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        } catch {
            wc.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    ~Balance()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    //Get the current balance for the user that is logged in.
    //If the balance returned from the server is NULL display error to the user.
    //Null could occur if the DB has been stopped or the server is down.       
    public void GetBalance(string sipUsername)
    {
        //Remove the underscore ( _ ) from the username, as this is not needed to get the balance.
        sipUsername = sipUsername.Remove(0, 1);

        string strURL =
            string.Format("https://www.xxxxxxx.com", 
            sipUsername);

        //Download only when the webclient is not busy.
        if (!wc.IsBusy)
        { 
            // Download the current balance.
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(strURL));             
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Busy please try again");
        }
    }

    //return and display the balance after the download has fully completed
    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Pass the result to the event handler
    }

    private bool isDisposed = false;

    //Dispose of the balance object
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!isDisposed)
            Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    //Remove the event handlers
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        isDisposed = true;
        if (disposing)
        {
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged -= new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            wc.Dispose();
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, would there be a problem with putting the:

wc.DownloadProgressChanged -= new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);

inside the destructor, rather than the Dispose? (As these are not unmanaged objects)? Is the issue that the dispose may make the object invalid, so you need to do them here instead?

Comment: `IDisposable` is a pattern for implementing deterministic disposal of resources.  All resources should be cleaned up in the Dispose method--once it runs, the finalizer is suppressed.  The only time the finalizer should run is if the object wasn't disposed properly.  The main reason the event handlers are removed is so that we can be certain that `wc_DownloadStringCompleted` isn't received after the object is disposed; that would be unexpected.

Comment: Zenox, you should never implement a finalizer unless you have to - it's for cleaning up unmanaged memory ONLY. You definitely don't want to refer to other objects in a finalizer as there is no guarantee they haven't already been disposed/finalized. See my answer below & for a longer answer get hold of the framework design guidelines. Basically you should always question whether a finalizer is required and check what it does very carefully. An unhandled exception from a finalizer crashes your application immediately with no chance to recover (how could it recover, it runs in it's own thread).

Comment: You should remove the finalizer/destructor. It doesn't belong, and you don't need it because the finalizer built into the existing webclient type will still run and take care of disposing that object.

Answer (score 8):

There are two correct ways to use an IDisposable object:

1. put it in a `using` block
   **OR**
2. Wrap it in a class that also *correctly* implements IDisposable and dispose it when this new class is disposed.  You now expect that all instances of your new class are created with `using` blocks.

Note that I said "or", not "and".  Do one or the other, but not both.

Here, when you create your WebClient instance with a `using` block in the constructor, you dispose it before you ever have a chance to use it anywhere else.  You should do just option two, in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have declared wc inside of a using statement you should not be used outside of that. So I would guess that your calls using wc inside of the GetBalance throw exceptions.
You should remove the using block from the Balance contstructor.

See "[using statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)" for more info on the using statement.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct but they have all missed the fact that you are declaring a finalizer when you shouldn't.

From the .Net Framework Design Guidelines (page 258):

- **Avoid** making types finalizable.
- **Do** make a type finalizable, if the type is responsible for releasing an unmanaged resources that does not have its own finalizer.

So the edited answer of rpetrich is correct, providing someone with edit privileges deletes the finalizer.

Comment: I'd suggest that types should generally only be Finalizable if they will never hold direct or indirect strong references to a large volume of objects that aren't needed for finalization.  If keeping an object around long enough to run a finalizer would also entail keeping around a large volume of other objects, the parts of the object which require finalization should be moved into a smaller finalizable class, so the larger class would no longer need a finalizer.